# POWERPIVOT - Conditional Division

Tags: dax

I have to use POWERPIVOT to make a presentation support and have to use measures.

I need to add a measure to calculate the % of fail based on the number of service:

But this formula returns an error:

```
= CALCULATE(DIVIDE(SUM( Table1[Quality]);Table1[Quality]="FAILED");COUNT(Table1[Serv])
```

| Quality | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| PASSED | FINAL |
| PASSED | FINAL |
| PENDING | FINAL |
| FAILED | INL |
| PASSED | INL |
| PENDING | FINAL |

16,7%*

I also tried:

```
=DIVIDE(Table1[Quality] = "FAILED";Table1[Quality]) or =CALCULATE(Table1[Quality] = "FAILED"/ Table1[Quality]) or = DIVIDE(COUNT(Table1[Quality] = "FAILED" ; COUNT(Table1[Quality])
```

Calculation error in measure 'Table1'[measure 1]: A single value for column 'Quality' in table 'Table1' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

```
= CALCULATE(DIVIDE(SUM( Table1[Quality]);Table1[Quality]="FAILED");COUNT(Table1[Serv])
```

Answer (score 1):

% Fail is pretty simple.

```
Fail Count:= COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table','Table'[Quality]="Failed"))
All records count:= CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(ALL('Table'))

% Fail = DIVIDE([Fail Count],[All records count])
```

If you have to do this for work, ask your boss to get you a copy of Rob Collie's book on DAX. It's a really gentle introduction.